# where para inner join

Tags: php, postgresql

como tenho três tabelas WHERE

```
select login, nome_hotel from extranet_login, extranet_hoteis, hoteis 
where extranet_login.id_login=extranet_hoteis.id_login 
and extranet_hoteis.id_hotel=hoteis.id_hotel 
and extranet_login.login='admin';
```

para INNER JOIN

```
SELECT login, nome_hotel
FROM extranet_login
INNER JOIN extranet_hoteis ON extranet_login.id_login = extranet_hoteis.id_login
INNER JOIN hoteis ON hoteis.id_hotel = extranet_hoteis.id_hotel
INNER JOIN extranet_login ON extranet_login.login = 'admin';
```

Está errado?

Comment: Não entendi porque deram -1 para você. Achei a pergunta pertinente. +1 para você para ajudar a recuperar um pouco a reputação. Infelizmente tem muita gente que fica dando -1 sem seguir as regras corretas do site.

Comment: Tentei ajudar, confira a resposta sff

Answer (score 2):

A sintaxe SQL seria algo assim:

```
select login, nome_hotel
  from extranet_login ext_log
 inner join extranet_hoteis ext_hot on ext_hot.id_login = ext_log.id_login
 inner join hoteis hot on hot.id_hotel = ext_hot.id_hotel
 where ext_log.login = 'admin';
```

No entanto, para esse tipo de consulta em que haja uma cláusula WHERE, pode ser interessante criar tabelas temporárias, de forma a reduzir o universo de consulta. Para esse caso parece ok, já que há a filtragem por um usuário em específico.

Comment: Deu erros :/
Query failed: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ext_hot" LINE 4: ... INNER JOIN hoteis hot ON hot.id_hotel = ext_hot.id...